# Returning the results of multiple 'WITH CTE' queries as one result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the highest price from the same product over `n` periods of time i.e. last 5, 50, 100, 500.
At the moment I'm running the query four times for above periods like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (500) * FROM Ticker WHERE ProductId='BTC-USD'
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM CTE 
ORDER BY PRICE desc
```

Is there a way I can get all the results at once in 4 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . My first thought is a `union all`:

```
with cte as (
      select top (500) t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from Ticker t
      where ProductId = 'BTC-USD'
      order by id desc
     )
select 500 as which, max(cte.price) as max_price from cte where seqnum <= 500 union all
select 100 as which, max(cte.price) from cte where seqnum <= 100 union all
select 50 as which, max(cte.price) from cte where seqnum <= 50 union all
select 5 as which, max(cte.price) from cte where seqnum <= 5;
```

But, I have another idea:

```
with cte as (
      select top (500) t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from Ticker t
      where ProductId = 'BTC-USD'
      order by id desc
     )
select v.which, x.max_price
from (values (5), (50), (100), (500)) v(which) cross apply
     (select max(price) as max_price from cte where seqnum <= which) x;
```

Of course, the "500" in the CTE needs to match the maximum value in `v`.  You can actually get rid of the `TOP` in the CTE.